# JDBC, Tomcat, context.xml and Oracle native encryption

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

I can add specific connection properties (for connection pooling, etc.) with JDBC/thin connections from Java to Oracle by using

```
props.put("connectionPoolName", "ConnPool");
props.put("description", "UCP JNDI Connection Pool");
props.put("factory", "oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl");
props.put("inactiveConnectionTimeout", "5");
props.put("user", "scott");
[...]
```

I can also use a context.xml for these settings, like:

```
description="UCP JNDI Connection Pool" 
connectionFactoryClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" 
factory="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl" 
inactiveConnectionTimeout="5"
user="scott"
```

So I tried setting Oracle 12 native encryption parameters in context.xml in *countless* ways, for example:

```
connectionProperties="oracle.net.encryption_client=(REQUIRED);oracle.net.encryption_types_client=(AES256);oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=(REQUIRED);oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=(SHA1)"
```

or

```
connectionProperties="oracle.net.encryption_client=REQUIRED"
connectionProperties="oracle.net.encryption_types_client=AES256"
connectionProperties="oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=REQUIRED"
connectionProperties="oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=SHA1"
(Which obviously doesn't work)
```

or

```
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT="REQUIRED"
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT="REQUIRED"
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT="AES256"
etc.
```

...and nothing works.
Does anybody know if you can set the client encryption parameters in context.xml? And if yes: how to do so?

The server is configured correctly and the encryption works when using option 1 or sqlplus client, but nothing gets encrypted by using context.xml, but *also* no errors are logged or anything, it just transfers unencrypted data.

I assume I miss something trivial, or just don't know the correct parameters for context.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the , as the separator as shown here. Check [OracleConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jajdb/index.html) for the correct name of the connection property.

```
 connectionProperties="{javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/myuser/cloud/truststore.jks, 
   javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS, javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=welcome1, 
   javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/myuser/cloud/keystore.jks, javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS, 
   javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=welcome1, 
   oracle.net.ssl_version=1.2, oracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match=true}"
```